# Doctrine 2, help on doing annotation for relations?

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm starting out with doctrine2. So, I'm taking the following example, to understand how to do annotations for table relationship, for example:

-------- the tables

USER
 id
 username
 group_id

GROUP
 id
 name

A given user, is part of a group (admin, member). For example,
john is admin
peter is member

```
<?php

/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="group")
     * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $group;
}

/** @Entity */
class group
{

}
?>
```

I would like to understand if this is correct ?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct as it is.

You could even ommit the @JoinColumn Statement as it will default to this values.

If you want a bidirectional relationship you also have to set the relationship on the group class like this:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="group")
private $users;
```